# Is there some reverse IPA dictionary for English?

Tags: discussion, pronunciation, ipa

I see that the word "query" is pronounced:

```
/ˈkwɪəri/
```

I was wondering whether there is any word in English that sounds:

```
/ˈkwiri/
```

Is there some kind of reverse pronunciation lookup resource online?

Comment: The combination /ir/ in English only occurs in compound words like *reread* and *three-ring*. (Although some Americans use the pronunciation [ir] for words containing /ɪər/.)

Comment: There's a website that does this for American English (although it doesn't use IPA). [See this question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113651/how-does-one-find-a-word-with-a-rhyming-middle-syllable)